# Apache http compoents server wire logs

Tags: java, logging, apache-httpcomponents

I am building a small application on top of HTTP server in Apache httpcomponents httpcore-4.4.1.jar. I want to have logs similar to http client wire logs `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire`. So far checking the code I could not find such thing, so I thought I could implement something similar on my own. I can override `org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.getSocketInputStream(Socket)` and `getSocketOutputStream` however I'm not sure how to "plug in" my new class into the server. 
Other ideas are also welcome, but please do not recommend capturing intermittent trafic with Wireshark or Fiddler etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 methods can be overridden in a class which extends `org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnection`. This new class needs to be returned by a class that is overriding `org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory.createConnection(Socket)` which can be then set to HTTP Server with `setConnectionFactory` method:

```
final HttpServer server = ServerBootstrap.bootstrap()
            .setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
            .setListenerPort(9090)
            .setHttpProcessor(httpProcessor)
            .setSocketConfig(socketConfig)
            .setExceptionLogger(new StdErrorExceptionLogger ())
            .setHandlerMapper(handle_map)
            .create();
    server.start();
```

Comment: Connection classes with wire / header logging can be copied from the HttpCore test package http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/xref-test/org/apache/http/testserver/package-summary.html